# About Canonical dropping Unity

Tags: 16.04, unity, canonical, gnome-shell

Canonical has dropped Unity, and has decided to switch to GNOME Shell for the future releases. Since Ubuntu 16.04 is an LTS release, does this mean that the LTS users won't receive any updates/fixes for their Unity DE?

And GNOME Shell is a totally different thing than what we've been using for so long! I'm thinking whether it's worth it continue using 16.04, since Unity is long gone...

Comment: This is sadly not how this site works, if you want an discussion you might have a look into [ubuntuforums.org](http://ubuntuforums.org). For a question and answer site your question is simply to broad and/or generates only opinion based answers.

Comment: Ubuntu 16.04LTS is supported for five years, so Canonical have said it will support Unity until EOL for 16.04 (2021). Support from Canonical includes only security updates; not new features. If you like Unity and want to know what is going on, i'd suggest community.ubuntu.com where there was a recent survey on 18.04 Ubuntu-Unity (which is now a community supported distro; daily test builds are now available). The key is security updates will continue until 14.04LTS & 16.04LTS are EOL.

Comment: Sadly, Canonical can not sustain it;s various ambitious projects and 17.10 is the way of the future.